# redirect from http to https in apache showing original url with arguments

Tags: apache, redirect

I'm running Apache 2.4.7 on Ubuntu, and I'd like to redirect traffic from http:// to https:// for all URLs. I'd like to show a page with a note to update bookmarks and a redirect after 5 seconds.

For example if loading http://example.com/one/two/three?param=x&param2=y, I'd like to show a page that reads something like:

> Please update your bookmark to point to:
>   https://example.com/one/two/three?param=x&param2=y you will be
>   redirected in 5 seconds.

I'm wondering if there's a simple way to do this with Apache directives and perhaps a single .html file to serve as a template for the above page.

Answer (score 1):

If its on a same domain, the best way to do this is using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) Use below in your Virtual Host configurations

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName example.com
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
   RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

This will redirect Users automatically to `https` version of your site with a correct request uri. There should not be any need for users to update their bookmarks.
Good Luck!

Comment: That looks like a good strategy but I was wondering specifically about how to implement the redirect page with a 5 second delay

Comment: What you can do is host [redirect.html](http://webmaster.iu.edu/tools-and-guides/maintenance/redirect-meta-refresh.phtml) on `http://example.com` and have users redirect to `http://example.com/redirect.html`. You can achieve this by editing the configurations in answer above. `RewriteEngine on` `RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/redirect.html [R=301,L]`

Comment: Can I show the original URL they loaded inside redirect.html?